# How to carry over some transfer budget into new season?

Tags: fifa-15

In Fifa 15 career mode unfortunately transfer budgets do not carry over from one season to the next. Nuts, stupid decision, EA - makes no sense.

Well - I have read that many people claim the solution is to first shift all your funds from transfer to wages and then extend a contract of a player you don't want giving him a salary that is 100% the salary you can afford.

I tried this - In my case that's about 1 million euro on a player of about 65 rating. Problem is, that in the next season I can't seem to sell the player. Clubs show interest and I accept - however, they seem to never agree with the player on the terms of the new contract.

What am I overlooking at this glitch? Is there an upper limit on the wage relative to their rating?
Is there another option to carry over the budget?

Comment: Are you expecting the club to pay more than a million euro to a mediocre player or the player to agree to a significant pay-cut? For him to move, one of those would need to happen.

Comment: Right, that makes sense to you and to me. However, I don't expect anything anymore from the AI of this game. It's atrocious and borderline sadistic how the board gives you $50m cash for cups that you can't spend - and just when you are about to be able to spend it, they take it. Where is reason here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't sell the player.**

What I like to do is:

1. Get an average player (71-76 rating) and make him available for loan. Clubs will be interested in him and loan him. This means that,
2. The available cash will now be in the wage budget. Now all you have to do is,
3. Transfer it into the transfer budget.

The good thing about this strategy is that when the player returns from loan, the budgets are not altered, which allows you to do it all over again continuously. I've made about 500 million dollars transfer budget with 1 million dollar wages within 4 seasons, and all the best players.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a glitch the clubs won't accept his terms. Because the player wants more than his previous contract, so if you give him a wage from 1 million the club is almost certainly not going to accept it.

As far as I know there is no maximum wage on a player.

It think the only way to carry over the budget is buying players for little money, and give them a contract for 1 year, and the next season you can sell them.

I don't know if this is helpful or not, but I did my best to help you.

Comment: This is helpful, it's the logical explanation and just what I thought happened. It is possible to use the exploit in the same season though, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not able to sell your player, try to release his contract. I haven't tried this but it just might work!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out another way to transfer:

Don't try to sell the highly paid player - instead buy a player and trade the highly paid player in. Afterwards you can move the available wages back to transfer funds.

This works like a charm and you don't lose a cent from one season to another :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick where you can carry over your transfer budget.

First move all your transfer budget to wage and then re-sign a player you want to sell on for all of your wage budget. Next season sell him and then you should get all the wage and the transfer fee you got from him. Proceed to balance out your transfer and wage budget, then you should have quite a bit of cash

Comment: Yeah - I already figured this is the right trick, please read the OP again. Problem is that negotiations never succeed. However, I figured out the answer and answered myself, see below.

Answer (score -1):

Transfer your budget to wages and sign players on free agent and sell them players in next transfer window you will get money for the player and wages you offered in the players contracts